# EU Cookie Compliance module not working

Tags: 7

got a problem with the [EU Cookie Compliance module](https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance). I installed it and it only worked when you were logged in (my site uses SSL).  Then I realized I hadn't set the permissions so that the cookies message is displayed to Anonymous users.  Now the message doesn't appear to anyone, logged in or not.  I've made sure the cookie is deleted from the browser, but still no luck.  Any ideas please?

The site is http://idea.nottingham.ac.uk.

No message displayed for anyone since I added Display permissions for anonymous users. Before, it wasn't displaying message for 'guests', only logged in users.

Interestingly, it does work (for both guests and logged-in users) on my Bitnami development copy of the website where SSL is switched off.

Comment: just wanted to confirm: no Cookie Compliance message displayed for 'guests'

Comment: No message displayed for anyone since I added Display permissions for anonymous users.  Before, it wasn't displaying message for 'guests', only logged in users.

Comment: Interestingly, it does work (for both guests and logged-in users) on my Bitnami development copy of the website where SSL is switched off.

Comment: Just checking your website and it looks like the module is working now but there's no SSL, is that the best solution you found? By the way it is one of the fastest loading websites I have visited in a long-while, how did you achieve that?

Comment: Andy, I used something else in the end as I couldn't get the module to work, so used cookieassistant.com in the end.  As for the speed, thanks for that, I think it's down to good hosting to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I used something else in the end as I couldn't get the module to work, so used cookieassistant.com in the end. As for the speed, thanks for that, I think it's down to good hosting to be honest. – pixelshrink